# Why is my GPU slower than CPU when training LSTM/RNN models?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nvidia, keras

My machine has the following spec:

CPU: Xeon E5-1620 v4

GPU: Titan X (Pascal)

Ubuntu 16.04

Nvidia driver 375.26

CUDA tookit 8.0

cuDNN 5.1

I've benchmarked on the following Keras examples with Tensorflow as the backed [reference](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/examples):

```
SCRIPT NAME                  GPU       CPU
stated_lstm.py               5sec      5sec 
babi_rnn.py                  10sec     12sec
imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py   240sec    116sec
imbd_lstm.py                 113sec    106sec
```

My gpu is clearly out performing my cpu in non-lstm models.

```
SCRIPT NAME                  GPU       CPU
cifar10_cnn.py               12sec     123sec
imdb_cnn.py                  5sec      119sec
mnist_cnn.py                 3sec      47sec
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 41):

If you use Keras, use [CuDNNLSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnnlstm) in place of [LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) or [CuDNNGRU](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnngru) in place of [GRU](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#gru). In my case (2 Tesla M60), I am seeing 10x boost of performance. By the way I am using batch size 128 as suggested by @Alexey Golyshev.

Comment: We all love 2^n :)

Comment: But what's the difference between LSTM and CuDNNLSTM?

Comment: My model, 64 batch size, performance improved from 22 minutes to 1 minutes by changing LSTM to CuDNNLSTM on my RTX 2070!

Answer (score 20):

Too small batch size. Try to increase.

Results for my GTX1050Ti:

```
imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py
batch_size      time
32 (default)    252
64              131
96              87
128             66

imdb_lstm.py
batch_size      time
32 (default)    108
64              50
96              34
128             25
```

Comment: I could increase batch size for both my gpu and cpu and they will both perform similarl, I would expect the gpu to perform better.  It also seems like we are getting similar times even though my graphics card is much stronger than the 1050ti. My gpu is clearly outperforming my cpu on cnns, but not lstm, why is that?

Comment: @agsolid Your CPU is very fast. My Core i3-4330 calculates imdb_lstm.py (batch=128) in 110s per epoch vs 25s on GPU. Your GPU is also faster than mine. Difference is in the percentage of utilization (your is lower).

Comment: How can i utilize my GPUs full power?

Comment: @agsolid Low utilization is not bad. This problems are too small for your TitanX. For example, in mnist_cnn.py my result is 12s vs 3s on your GPU (you are 4x faster). On TitanX you can solve much more bigger problems that even will not fit in my GPU's memory.

Comment: **For imdb_lstm.py:**
`[GPU] GTX 760:
150s/epoch (32 batch size),
37s/epoch (128 batch size).

... [CPU] 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7-4870HQ:
88s/epoch (32 batch size),
50s/epoch (128 batch size)`
So my GPU only begins to perform better at the large batch sizes.
**Questions:** @AlexeyGolyshev
What's the downside of having a large batch size - does it reduce the prediction accuracy?
What's the best way of choosing a suitable batch size?

Comment: I upvoted this answer. In my case, increasing the batch size improved performance in about the same amount for both CPU and GPU. So this answer probably does not address the original question. But it is still very nice to boost the performance by only adjusting the batch size.

Answer (score 13):

It's just a tip.

**Using GPU is powerful when**

*1. your neural network model is big.* 
*2. batch size is big.*

It's what I found from googling.

Comment: The problem is "why GPU is slower than CPU in Keras LSTM / GRU", not "when should I use GPU". It is stated in the documentation: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/

Answer (score 5):

I have got similar issues here:

## Test 1

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz

Ubuntu 14.04

`imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py`: **155s**

## Test 2

GPU: GTX 860m

Nvidia Driver: 369.30

CUDA Toolkit: v8.0

cuDNN: v6.0

`imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py`:**450s**

## Analyse

When I observe the GPU load curve, I found one interesting thing:

- for lstm, GPU load jumps quickly between ~80% and ~10%

[GPU load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pnyB.png)

This is mainly due to the sequential computation in LSTM layer. Remember that LSTM requires sequential input to calculate hidden layer weights iteratively, in other words, you must wait for hidden state at time `t-1` to calculate hidden state at time `t`.

That's not a good idea for GPU cores, since they are many small cores who like doing computations in parallel, sequential compuatation can't fully utilize their computing powers. That's why we are seeing GPU load around 10% - 20% most of the time.

But in the phase of backpropagation, GPU could run derivative computation in parallel, so we can see GPU load peak around 80%.

Comment: `GTX 860m` is a mobile GPU and thus has extremely limited bandwidth and vram. I would strongly recommend against analysing anything on mobile gpus.

Comment: I tested my own c-lstm model last night (1 cnn layer + 1 lstm layer) using both ``GTX 860m`` and ``GTX 1060``. It turns out that 1060 is only **1.28** times faster than 860m. So I would like to assert that 1060 is still slower than CPU for ``imdb_bidirectional_lstm``. Will test my idea tonight.

Comment: ``GTX 1060``: one epoch takes ``320s``

Comment: @ZekunZhang How do you get the GPU load graph?

Comment: This is the only good answer. Recurrent neural networks cannot be parallelized beyond parallelizing the batches, and so the GPU isn't such a big increase in performance with respect to CPU, unlike other models like CNN for instance where everything can be parallelized.