# Keras: real amount of GPU memory used

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow backend and looking at `nvidia-smi` is not sufficient to understand how much memory current network architecture need because seems like Tensorflow just allocate all availible memory.

So the question is how to find out real GPU memory usage?

Comment: Have you tried out 'model.summary()' ? It should give some idea about the model memory usage.

Comment: @orabis yes, but it's only weights, if we train model Tensorflow also allocates itermediate blobs and gradients blobs + some overhead, I don't know how to precisely calculate memory usage.

Answer (score 13):

It can be done using Timeline, which can give you a full trace about memory logging. Similar to the code below:

```
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import tensorflow as tf


with K.get_session()  as s:
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
     
    # your fitting code and s run with run_options 

    to = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    trace = to.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open('full_trace.json', 'w') as out:
            out.write(trace)
```

If you want to limit the gpu memory usage, it can alse be done from gpu_options. Like the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.2
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Check the following documentation about the [Timeline](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py) object

As you use TensorFlow in the backend, you can use [tfprof](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/tfprof/README.md) profiling tool

Comment: The problem is if you run `fit`, follows by `session.run`, by the time your instrumented `run` call starts, bulk of memory allocated by `fit` will have been deallocated. There's a related issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9868  What's missing is a recipe of getting Keras to use custom `run_options`, or adding custom ops to keras model (like `MaxBytesInUse` op like [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ff2da4156bcde26a253fd98198c6f9389df921d9/tensorflow/contrib/memory_stats/python/kernel_tests/memory_stats_ops_test.py#L67) )

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `nvidia-smi` after telling TensorFlow not to reserve all memory of the GPU, but to grow this reservation on demand:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```