# Preload whole dataset on gpu for training Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a specific case where the networks are relatively tiny and for convergence and generalization matters I should maintain small batch sizes (e.g. 256), which leads to hundreds of batches to process per epoch.

Unfortunately, in this scenario batch, loading, and loss calculation becomes a bottleneck (as `timeline` tool tells me).

In TensorFlow, you can write something like this to load the data on the GPU:

```py
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    train_data = tf.constant(train_data_numpy)
```

But if I pass `train_data` to Keras `Model.predict` or `Model.fit` functions, I get the following error:

```py
keras/engine/training.pyc in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
   1515         f = self.predict_function
   1516         return self._predict_loop(f, ins,
-> 1517                                   batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
   1518 
   1519     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

keras/engine/training.pyc in _predict_loop(self, f, ins, batch_size, verbose)
   1129         if verbose == 1:
   1130             progbar = Progbar(target=samples)
-> 1131         batches = _make_batches(samples, batch_size)
   1132         index_array = np.arange(samples)
   1133         for batch_index, (batch_start, batch_end) in enumerate(batches):

keras/engine/training.pyc in _make_batches(size, batch_size)
    368         A list of tuples of array indices.
    369     """
--> 370     num_batches = int(np.ceil(size / float(batch_size)))
    371     return [(i * batch_size, min(size, (i + 1) * batch_size))
    372             for i in range(0, num_batches)]

AttributeError: 'Dimension' object has no attribute 'ceil'
```

Which makes sense, since Keras expects only NumPy-like arrays and lists of such.

Having said that, I also tried *pyCUDA* and *cupy* arrays, since they say to be NumPy-like... but those produce the following errors:

```py
keras/engine/training.pyc in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
   1515         f = self.predict_function
   1516         return self._predict_loop(f, ins,
-> 1517                                   batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
   1518 
   1519     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

keras/engine/training.pyc in _predict_loop(self, f, ins, batch_size, verbose)
   1139                 ins_batch = _slice_arrays(ins, batch_ids)
   1140 
-> 1141             batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
   1142             if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
   1143                 batch_outs = [batch_outs]

keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2266         updated = session.run(self.outputs + [self.updates_op],
   2267                               feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2268                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2269         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2270 

tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1091             feed_handles[subfeed_t] = subfeed_val
   1092           else:
-> 1093             np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
   1094 
   1095           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and

numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array
```

I tried googling this issue, but the only reasonable match is some Chinese blog post, which basically suggests patching Keras, which is impractical obviously.

I wonder what is the correct way to preload the whole dataset on GPU for Keras.

Useful info: I am using Keras 2.0.6 with TF 1.3, upgrading to 2.0.8/1.4 stack is yet unavailable due to crucial API changes, but would definitely be sped up in case it solves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to load the whole data. You can ingest the data piece by piece using the [DataSet](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) class.

Tensorflow can take care of loading more data while your gpu is crunching your numbers. You can follow the below steps.

1. Convert your dataset into a TFRecord dataset and save it to your disk.
2. Load this dataset using the TFRecordDataset class
3. Ingest it into your Kerasmodel.

You can check the example listed [here](https://medium.com/@moritzkrger/speeding-up-keras-with-tfrecord-datasets-5464f9836c36).

Hope this is helpful.